# Convert time string to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

If I have, for example, a string that contains 12:20pm or 4:34am and want to create a DateTime Object with that string?

Essentially, I have a date picker and next to it a jquery time picker and so I want to combine those two to get a combined DateTime object that has both the user selected date as well as the user selected time.

Comment: What do you want as a result when you _combine_ them? Can you give an example of combined result? Combining these values does **not** generate any `DateTime`.

Comment: @SonerGönül A `DateTime` object

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @ChristopherBonilla But what value as a `DateTime` exactly?

Comment: @SonerGönül so from the date picker i'd have 06/10/2015 and from time picker i'd have 2:47am. So combined I would have 06/10/2015 2:47am

Comment: Is it definitely C# you need? Is it a JavaScript date object you are after? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    string date = "2015-06-10";
    string time = " 12:20pm";
    DateTime combinedResult = DateTime.Parse(date + time);
    Console.WriteLine(combinedResult.ToString());
```

The DateTime.Parse method converts string object to datetime object
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: This does not work, it gives error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." I think I need to try one of the other ParseExact methods mentioned and provide the exact format of my string

Comment: Actually, scratch that, I had a typo, worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DateTime.ParseExact()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131038%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method with desired format string.

Answer (score 1):

With DateTime.Parse() you can parse any string into a DateTime object. If the values of your two pickers have different formats, you can provide the combined format as a 2nd parameter to the Parse function.

Answer (score 1):

```
    You can this is simple way to do it.

    string tm = "10:24PM";
    string dt = "6/10/2015";
    DateTime dt2 = Convert.ToDateTime(dt + " "+tm);
    Response.Write(dt2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the time span, something like below :

```
TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.ParseExact("23:59:59(Your string)", "HH:mm:ss", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to make a string to combine date and time. I don't know the jquery time picker, but if it provides a DateTime oject you can do

```
var combined = datePicker.Value.Add(timePicker.Value.TimeOfDay);
```